# Can't get SQL server name

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to add new data source via the data source configuration wizard. I'm using Microsoft SQL Server as data source and .NET framework Data Provider for SQL Server as data provider. In the next window where I have to choose the server name, the list is empty. So I thought one of the SQL services are not working, I opened services.msc and there were 6 services, from which only SQL services vss writer was enabled. I enabled all of them (SQL Server, SQL Server agent, SQL Server browser, SQL Server Active Directory Helper) but the list still is empty. What should I do?

Comment: perhaps you can check this link. [Click here](http://www.sqldbatips.com/showarticle.asp?ID=45 "Enumerating SQL Servers on the Network")!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL Browser service is the one used to allow other machines to discover the SQL server's existence on the network, though this requires TCP/IP or Named Pipes to be enabled in the SQL configuration, so check that too.

Also check your firewall isn't blocking the UDP port 1434 (and TCP port 1433 for that matter) [note, these are the default ports; they *can* be changed in the configuration).

Answer (score 0):

The problem here might be your Database might not have permission over network..
Just try to connect by using Sql Authentication using sa account and password.. This should help you.

The other reason might be if you are using Visual studio 2010 it wont show database from Sql Server 2000

Accept or Vote up if it works for you.